# Como alterar uma tag meta em um SPA?

Tags: javascript, html, seo, single-page-application

Eu tenho um SPA feito com javascript puro, e precisava alterar o meta description depois de um evento, por exemplo, um click.

Utilizando javascript eu consigo mudar, mas creio que para o crawler do Google isso não faz diferença.

Isso está correto?

Existe algum outro modo de alterar o meta description de uma página que não tem reload? Algo utilizando hash?

Comment: Não faz sentido alterar um meta depois da página servida. Se é um SPA, é uma página só, se quer indexação diferente por "parte" do SPA, precisa tratar os URLs gerados individualmente (controlar os meta do lado do servidor, dependendo do URL acessado). Exemplo: se o usuário acessou o SPA por http://aplicacao/caminho2, serve o meta de caminho2. Se acessoi http://aplicacao/caminho1, serve o meta de caminho1 (isso independe de você usar a mesma página pra servir os 2 caminhos)

Comment: Em outras palavras: não é que vc precisa alterar o meta depois do clique, e sim você precisa alterar o meta quando o URL gerado pelo clique for acessado futuramente. Os crawlers que vão usar o meta normalmente não vão navegar pelo seu SPA clicando os links, eles vão fazer requisições individuais (como se fossem páginas separadas). Por isso é bom saber usar a API de histórico, e configurar o servidor para lidar bem com URLs iniciando por funções específicas do SPA.